# What are some unnecessary processes in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, nfs, ubuntu-12.04, django

So, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 for my AWS instances and when I first start it up and look at the processes there seems to be a lot of things running that I'm not sure are necessarily needed for my purposes.

My instance is essentially just needs to run Apache2, Django, MongoDB, the NFS service and all few other services that those depend on. Is there a guide to what the other processes do or what I can clean up?

Comment: The default Ubuntu AMIs on AWS are pretty bare-bones. What you're seeing are likely system processes that are required.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with a "core install" and install only what you really need on the Ubuntu instance . Installing Apache2 will install all only the necessary dependencies and so on .